# how to remove item from Recyclerview

Tags: android

friends...

In my project, I am creating a list of images from the server and showing in Recyclerview.

now I want to remove a particular item from the list when I click on the verify button.

I tried to hide `holder.itemview` but its see again when I scroll.

I just want to remove or hide that item which is verified once.

here is my code :

1) **Main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String url = "www.mysite.com/api/api-id-list.php?action=imgs";

private ProgressDialog mDetailProgress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main_activity);

    LoadRecyclerView();
}

private void LoadRecyclerView() {

    mDetailProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mDetailProgress.setTitle("Loading images");
    mDetailProgress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    mDetailProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    mDetailProgress.show();

    final RecyclerView imgList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.imgList);

    imgList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
            Image[] images = gson.fromJson(response, Image[].class);

            imgList.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, images));
            mDetailProgress.dismiss();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Something went wrong..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(request);
}}
```

2) **ImageAdapter**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

private ProgressDialog mDetailProgress;

private Context context;
private Image[] data;

Button btn_ban, btn_verify;
private View view;

public ImageAdapter (Context context, Image[] data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ImageViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Image imagelist = data[position];

    holder.userCode.setText(imagelist.getCode());
    Glide.with(holder.userImage.getContext()).load(imagelist.getIdPhoto()).into(holder.userImage);

    btn_verify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() { return data.length; }

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView userCode;
    ImageView userImage;

    public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        userImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_iv_img);
        userCode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_tv_code);
        btn_ban = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_ban);
        btn_verify = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_verify);
    }

}}
```

3) **Image.java**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Image {

@SerializedName("per_ID")
@Expose
private String perID;
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private String code;
@SerializedName("first_nm")
@Expose
private String firstNm;
@SerializedName("last_nm")
@Expose
private String lastNm;
@SerializedName("photo_ID")
@Expose
private String photoID;
@SerializedName("id_photo")
@Expose
private String idPhoto;

public String getPerID() {
    return perID;
}

public void setPerID(String perID) {
    this.perID = perID;
}

public Image withPerID(String perID) {
    this.perID = perID;
    return this;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public Image withCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
    return this;
}

public String getFirstNm() {
    return firstNm;
}

public void setFirstNm(String firstNm) {
    this.firstNm = firstNm;
}

public Image withFirstNm(String firstNm) {
    this.firstNm = firstNm;
    return this;
}

public String getLastNm() {
    return lastNm;
}

public void setLastNm(String lastNm) {
    this.lastNm = lastNm;
}

public Image withLastNm(String lastNm) {
    this.lastNm = lastNm;
    return this;
}

public String getPhotoID() {
    return photoID;
}

public void setPhotoID(String photoID) {
    this.photoID = photoID;
}

public Image withPhotoID(String photoID) {
    this.photoID = photoID;
    return this;
}

public String getIdPhoto() {
    return idPhoto;
}

public void setIdPhoto(String idPhoto) {
    this.idPhoto = idPhoto;
}

public Image withIdPhoto(String idPhoto) {
    this.idPhoto = idPhoto;
    return this;
}}
```

Comment: take the index of item you want to remove and remove it from your Image array. and call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter

Comment: response set again with complete list when you scroll to not set response gain only change data of list which is verified and notify data change in adapter

Comment: ok thanks, I will try it.

Comment: Remove option not avail for Image[]. what to do.? I am a beginner for android, can you please paste the piece of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make data not `array`, but `List`, so it's easy to remove item;

Secondly set listener for verify button inside ViewHolder and inside `OnClick` remove item and notify adapter.

```
 btn_verify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
});
```

**Note:** Setting `OnClickListener` inside ViewHolder makes sure that only correct item is removed by using `getAdapterPosition()` to get correct position.
Position provided by `onBindViewHolder` might be invalid after new items are inserted.

Comment: Thanks you for Code.

Comment: I changed data array to List<Image>... 

now when i remove "data.remove(position)",

and generate Toast it's giving me wrong data(ImageList.getPhotoID).

what to do?

Comment: @DhavalJethva Do you make toast before removing item or after? and what does `data(ImageList.getPhotoID)` mean?

Comment: On btn click, I want to send photo_ID with verify=1 and after verify request want to hide an item of recyclerview.

Sorry. By mistake, I posted data(imagelist.getPhotoID())
but it was actually like this (imagelist.getPhotoID)

its worked for the first item, In second Toast its give me wrong photo_ID.

Comment: I generate Toast before item remove in btn onclick.

Comment: it should be `data.get(position).getPhotoID()`;